# How can I select multiple values in dropdownList in asp.net with VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am creating a page in which I need to show a drop down List. From this drop down List a user can select multiple values. I know I could use a check box list like:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" style="margin-right: 158px">
    <asp:ListItem>Value 1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Value 2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Value 3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Value 4</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

but if there are more than 50 or so values then that will consume a lot of space on the page and will look odd. So kindly tell me how can I select multiple values from drop down list or if there any alternatives so that I can select multiple values and show many records on a minimum space but not a grid?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is a [ListBox](http://www.startvbdotnet.com/aspsite/controls/listbox.aspx).   What you will want to do is apply CSS to allow it to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

you can use List box control with the SelectionMode property set to Multpile. [Listbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox.aspx)

if you need dropdownList only, then you can check this example [Multi Select DropDown](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/user-controls/MultiSelectDropdownList.aspx)